# Node.js script should wait before service is running

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I have a node.js script which starts at boot. It uses node-redis to create a client for Redis, but at boot Redis is not ready while node is already starting. So, it gives an exception and stops executing.

The first part looks like this:

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    jobs   = require("jobs"),
    client = redis.createClient(),
    runner = new jobs(client, "job-queue",{});

// Continue using runner
```

The exception is thrown in line 3 (`redis.createClient()`).

My solution was to make an endless loop, create the client in a try/catch and when successful, stop the loop:

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    jobs   = require("jobs"),
    queue  = 'job-queue',
    client = null,
    runner = null,
    createClient = function (redis, jobs, queue) {
        try {
            client = redis.createClient();
            return new jobs(client, queue, {});
        } catch (err) {
            return null;
        }
    };

while(true) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        runner = createClient(redis, jobs, queue);
    }, 1000);

    if (null !== runner) break;
}

// Continue using runner
```

After a couple of seconds, this is the output:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

How can I solve this? I am searching for a solution which could be in php:

```
while (true) {
    $client = createClient($redis, $jobs, $queue);
    if ($client instanceof MyClient) break;
    else sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: If two startup services have dependencies, easyest thing to do is ensure to start in right order, i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` is *asynchronous*. JavaScript (and Node.js) have very few functions that wait for something to happen before continuing (like `sleep`). Instead, execution continues to the next line right away, but you pass `setTimeout` a callback function which is run when it fires.

I would do something like this (warning, untested):

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
    jobs   = require("jobs"),
    queue  = 'job-queue';

function initializeRedis(callback) {
    (function createClient(){
        var runner;
        try {
            client = redis.createClient();
            runner = new jobs(client, queue, {});
        } catch (e) {}
        if (runner){
            callback(runner);
        } else {
            setTimeout(createClient, 1000);
        }
    })();
};

initializeRedis(function(runner){
    // Continue using runner
});
```

Comment: This aspect oriented example seems a bit better than @Fosco's one (sorry Fosco), I'll mark this as an answer soon. Atm, exceptions in redis.createClient() are not caught by my try/catch. When I figured this out, I'll give you the credits.

Comment: @JurianSluiman Not a problem, deleted mine as it proved not to be a correct answer.  I was pondering a solution with process.nexttick but didn't get around to it.

Comment: @Sidnicious, I assume that you wanted to write `setTimeout(createClient, 1000);`? Because this is wrong, it'll callback before success if the first attempt fails. It'll even call back more than once!

Comment: @thejh I don't completely follow… but I think I see what you mean. Does this fix it?

Comment: @Sidnicious: ah, sorry, I wanted to say `return setTimeout(createClient, 1000);`... but this should fix it, too, although it's an unusual style.

Comment: @thejh Good point. Looking at it again, that code schedules another try only if an error is thrown, but calls back only if `runner` is non-null. That *is* unusual. I just edited again, I think this better embodies the spirit of the original.