# Catch exception in node.js

Tags: javascript, exception, node.js

I have a simple program, which needs to make sure I can connect to a Redis server. I use node-redis to connect and need to wait until Redis is started. I use this piece of code:

```
function initializeRedis(callback) {
    (function createClient(){
        var runner;
        try {
            client = redis.createClient();
        } catch (e) {
            setTimeout(createClient, 1000);
        }
        callback();
    })();
};

initializeRedis(function() {
// Work here
});
```

This is because without the try/catch, I got an exception from node.js:

```
 node.js:134
         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
         ^ Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - ECONNREFUSED, Connection refused
     at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/php-jobs/node_modules/redis/index.js:88:28)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
     at Array.<anonymous> (net.js:830:27)
     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

When I start redis-server (Ubuntu machine) and start this script, everything works fine. If I stop redis-server and start the script, it doesn't catch the exception and still throws this same exception. How is that possible? I have a try/catch statement!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After `client = redis.createClient();`, set a handler for the `error` event:

```
client.on('error', function(err) {
  // handle async errors here
});
```

Have a look at the stack trace - your code isn't in it, so there's no place where a try/catch could catch the error.

Comment: If the error is asynchronous, how would I be able to wait until I have a valid connection? The problem in my startup cycle is this node script is started with upstart and redis with init.d. Apparently, node starts earlier and I have to wait until redis is ready too. That's what I am trying with the setTimeout() and callback here.

Comment: @JurianSluiman: You don't wait for it, you listen for it. And don't use setTimeout for this kind of stuff, it makes kittens **DIE**!

Comment: obviously the setTimeout() won't work with this client.on('error') handler, but the problem is I need to WAIT before I can continue because I DEPEND on the client. The callback() is triggered now because no exception is thrown and AFTER that I probably get this error triggered. Aynchronously processing errors sucks because if you depend on the result, you can't really do anything about that?

Comment: @JurianSluiman: huh, what? I don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: TL;DR: I cannot just "wait" asynchronously for the error because I synchrously depend on the client. Your callback handle is therefore no solution. See my question about the waiting part here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786660/node-js-script-should-wait-before-service-is-running

Comment: In the end there is no way to synchronously catch the exception, which is confirmed by the node-redis developer. This is not a satisfying answer, but @thejh is correct here.